# return first element if none clicked jquery

Tags: jquery

Im working on a video thumb gallery. I couldnt figure out how to do it the other way...This works but i would like to return the first video by default. I think I have to add a true/false statement to show the first if none have been clicked? Thanks in advance.

```
$('.thumb').live('click', function() {
          $('.thumb').not(this).next().removeClass('showVid');
    if(!$(this).next().hasClass('showVid'))
    {

        $(this).next().addClass('showVid');

    }


});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is asking... are you wanting to return the first one  by default inside of the click or by default after the page is loaded?

Comment: What exactly does clicking on `.thumb` do?

Comment: It displays a div that contains a video. Yes, I'd like the first to display on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Question/description is a bit vague but sounds like you want to cycle the thumbs and return to beginning

```
$('.thumb').live('click', function() {
     $('.showVid').removeClass('showVid');
     var next=$(this).next();
     // if next doesn't exist, go to first
     next.length ? next.addClass('showVid')  : $('.thumb:first').addClass('showVid');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first `.thumb` to be selected on page load, add

```
$('.thumb:first').trigger('click');
```

after binding your handler.